# How to dynamically alter column width in bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, bootstrap-grid

I want to place number of columns in a row dynamically. For example each student in students list should have one column.
The width of the column should depend on number of students.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks
Salman

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap 5, you can just use the col class, and it will stretch to fill the space. Then you can set the min-width of the elements in CSS with media breakpoints to get it to wrap when you want.

```
<div class="col" *ngFor="let student of studentList"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @z4nzib4r
I Should have mentioned I am using bootstrap 3

Comment: In that case, you are stuck doing a bunch of if statements on ng-containers.